# get 3rd level sub category in main menu Opencart v3.0

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I m try to get sub in sub category for opencart 3.x, I have change code in menu.php controller and menu.twig file but therer is no display sub of sub categoty.
I have Edit code in catalogcontroller/common/menu.php

```
public function index() {

    $this->load->language('common/menu');
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $data['categories'] = array();

    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                // Level 3
                $children_data2 = array();
                $children2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);
                foreach ($children2 as $child2) {
                    $children_data2[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child2['name'],
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'].'_'.$child2['category_id'])
                    );
                }

                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'children'=>$children_data2,
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
            }

            // Level 1
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }
    }

    return $this->load->view('common/menu', $data);
}
```

and also change in common/menu.twig file.

```
{% if child.children %}
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
       {% for child in child.children %}
          <li>
             <a href="{{ child.href }}" >{{ child.name }}</a>
          </li>
       {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**Controller**:
catalog\controller\common\menu.php

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonMenu extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('common/menu');

        // Menu
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category['top']) {
                // Level 2
                $children_data = array();

                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach ($children as $child) {

                    // Level 3
                    $grandchildren_data = array();

                    $grandchildren = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

                    foreach ($grandchildren as $grandchild) {

                        $grandchild_filter_data = array(
                            'filter_category_id'  => $grandchild['category_id'],
                            'filter_sub_category' => true
                        );

                        $grandchildren_data[] = array(
                            'name'  => $grandchild['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($grandchild_filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $grandchild['category_id'])
                        );
                    }


                    $filter_data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
                        'children' => $grandchildren_data,
                    );
                }

                // Level 1
                $data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->load->view('common/menu', $data);
    }
}
```

**View**:
catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\menu.twig

```
{% if categories %}
<div class="container">
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for child in children %}
                    <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a>
                        {% if child.children %}
                            <ul>
                                {% for children in child.children %}
                                    <li><a href="{{ children.href }}">{{ children.name }}</a></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %}</div>
            <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a> </div>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Finally you may need to clear your caches, twig cache, ocmod caches, etc...